# Multi level JSON reading and writing IOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios8, multi-level

So the last two days I have been struggling to get data from and to a JSON file, this is because it has multiple levels and the same names. I did not set up this file and can't change the structure so I have to get it working in the way it is. To Pharse JSON form a single level is no problem and it works fine, what I need is to get separate data block from "GOV" and "PRIV" then I need a data block "GENERAL" and "LOCAL" and within those I need to be able to get the "Hospital information as a block but also the separate values. Now I have been trying to get this done for two days and I know im doing something wrong but cant figure it out. I do get data back for example the "GOV" block but then in the output window it is showing a array with access data (<__NSCFArray 0x7fe711f58800>) and the output... I cant break up this output and that is what I need because every value needs to be in a text file in a tableview cell. I know { } denotes NSDictionary [ ] denotes NSArray and I have been reading a lot about JSON and I get the concept but There is little to non for me understandable info when it comes to multi level JSON and equal names (hospital) in this case. I have tried all the available option I could find here on StackOverflow but no succes. So if somebody can push me in the right way I will be gratefull.. part of the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

_jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

_AppListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


NSArray *wrapper= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *avatars = [wrapper objectAtIndex:0];




for(NSDictionary *apps in _jsonArray) {
    if([[apps objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"GOV"]){
       NSDictionary*tmp = [apps objectForKey:@"hospital"];
        _AppListArray = [tmp objectForKey:@"area"];
    }
}

//returns error because _ApplistArray is an array and it can't read the data from the objectkey  
for (int i = 0;  i < _jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSString *appName = [[_AppListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"hospitalname"];
    NSString *appCondition = [[_AppListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"condition"];
    NSString *app avgrating = [[_AppListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"avgrating"];


    [_AppListArray addObject:[[Applist alloc]initWithAppName:appName andAppCondition:appCondition andAppURL:appURL]];

}
```

The _ApplistArray does return the 1ste Hospital data block but as an array and this is were I get stuck.. I need to get another level deeper.....Again the solution probably is easy but JSON is something I never worked with this is my first go. The JSON where I need to get the data from:

```
[


-{
    -hospital: {
            -area: [
                 -{
                     -hospital: [
                                 -{
                                 hospitalname: "ABC",
                                 avgrating: "2,6",
                                 condition: "UPDATE NEEDED",
                                 },
                                 -{
                                 hospitalname: "DEF",
                                 avgrating: "4,2",
                                 condition: "FINE",
                                 },
                                 ],
                 name: "GENERAL"
                 }
                 ]
     },
    title: "GOV"
 },
  -{
     -hospital: {
            -area: [
                 -{
                     -hospital: [
                            -{
                                hospitalname: "GHI",
                                avgrating: "3",
                                condition: "INSTALL NEW",
                                },
                                -{
                                hospitalname: "JKL",
                                avgrating: "0",
                                condition: "NEW",
                                },
                                 ],
                 name: "LOCAL"
                 }
                    ]
     },
    title: "PRIV"
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you update the whole JSON with out any edit on it?

Comment: Remove dashes`(-)` from your json and take help of this json serializer: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. I believe you will understand it better.

Comment: [{"hospital":{"area":[{"hospital":[{"hospitalname":"ABC","avgrating":"2,6","condition":"UPDATE NEEDED"},{"hospitalname":"DEF","avgrating":"4,2","condition":"FINE"}],"name":"GENERAL"}]},"title":"GOV"},{"hospital":{"area":[{"hospital":[{"hospitalname":"GHI","avgrating":"3","condition":"INSTALL NEW"},{"hospitalname":"JKL","avgrating":"0","condition":"NEW"}],"name":"LOCAL"}]},"title":"PRIV"}]

Comment: This is flat JSON @Vino can't show more because of security issues....

Comment: @Ecko No worries. I have updated my answer. Check it

Comment: It's just a bunch of dictionaries and arrays, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
NSArray *hospitals = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"mainKey"];// I assumed you getting with some key but change based on your requirement
for (NSDictionary *mainData in hospitals){ // Start of Main Hospital
    NSDictionary *hospital = [mainData objectForKey:@"hospital"];
    NSArray *areas = [hospital objectForKey:@"area"];
    for(NSDictionary *area in areas){// Start of Area
        NSArray *innerHospitals = [area objectForKey:@"hospital"];
        for(NSDictionary *innerHospital in innerHospitals){
            NSString *hospitalName = [innerHospital objectForKey:@"hospitalname"];
            NSString *avgrating =[innerHospital objectForKey:@"avgrating"];
            NSString *condition =[innerHospital objectForKey:@"condition"];
            // Do What Ever you want here
        }
        NSString *name =[area objectForKey:@"name"];

    }// End Of Area
    NSString *title =[mainData objectForKey:@"title"];

} // End of Main Hospital
```

I haven't tested it. But i assume this will work. Have a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks it works poerfect, I knew it was something easy... just didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need 2 for loops for each "Area".
Area is an Array (1st loop) and each hospital is another Array (2nd loop).
And inside each hospital element is the dictionary with the values you need.

ignoring loops this is how you get the first hospitalname(ABC) assuming _AppListArray has the contents of Area

```
NSString *appName = _AppListArray[0][@"hospital"][0][@"hospitalname"];
```

For each 0 you will replace it with the counters for the for loops.

Comment: Such *blind* accessing of objects in an array will cause an out-of-bounds exception sometimes, given the changing nature of data delivered externally.  Better is to test the array counts first and access them second.

Comment: Yes, that's why i said that the OP needs to do it inside 2 for-loops. The example that i posted was just a placeholder.